# error de sintaxis esta alrededor del IDENTIFIED BY

Tags: mysql, sql, ubuntu

Estoy intentando instalar WordPress en ubuntu y me sale el siguiente error de sintaxis:
El codigo es el siguiente:

`GRANT ALL ON WordPressBD. *TO 'NOMBRE DE USUARIO'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'contraseña';`

Si hago esto seria igual o estoy haciendo algo diferente:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'nuevousuario'@'localhost';
```

Me sale que error de sintaxis esta alrededor del `IDENTIFIED BY`también lo he intentado con `IDENTIFIED PASSWORD`y nada .
Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes dos manera de crear el usuario y asignarle los privilegios

**Opcion 1:**

Primero creas el usuario:

```
CREATE USER 'nombre_usuario'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'tu_contrasena';
```

Luego otorgas los permisos:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'nombre_usuario'@'%';
```

**Opcion 2:**

Creas el usuario y al mismo tiempo otorgas los permisos:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'nombre_usuario'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'tu_contraseña';
```

Comment: Recuerda aceptar la respuesta y dar voto a favor si fue de tu utilidad. En este [Enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) te explica como hacerlo. Saludos!